# Why Excel can't find the lookup reference but still returns a valid result?

Tags: excel, vlookup

In an Excel file I saw lookups on several cells that look like this:

```
@SomeString
@AnotherString
```

Both return some values. I didn't know or use `@` command before but now learn that it's a kind of lookup. Now if I find `SomeString` by looking in the value across the whole workbook, I can locate the lookup. However I can't find `AnotherString` that way.

Is there any way I can find the lookup location? Additionally, is it possible that if the lookup is in fact deleted from the workbook, the value returned from a previous reference is still valid, as it may be the case here?

UPDATE: It turns out they refer to several defined names.

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: Is the @ symbol in the formula or is it part of text string?

Comment: @ is part of the whole entry in a cell, so you'll see `@SOIsAwesome` in cell A7 for example. I think it's the pointer to the subsequent formula string.